# java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup, ioexception

I am parsing some lyrics site, and i have error from the header.
URL, that i give to it (for example):
http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/linkinpark/intheend.html

```
class GetLyrics extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String url = urls[0];
    String output;
    output = "If you see this, some kind of error has occupied";
    try {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); //I dont know how it works, its google
        document.outputSettings(new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));//makes html() preserve linebreaks and spacing
        document.select("br").append("\\n");
        Elements lyrics = document.select("b + br + br + div"); //Search for lyrics <div> tag, that after <b> and 2 <br> tags
        String s = lyrics.html().replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n"); //Google again
        output = Jsoup.clean(s, "", Whitelist.none(), new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
        output = output.replace("\n\n", "\n");
        output = output.substring(4); //Remove first enters
    }
    catch (HttpStatusException e) {
        System.err.println("404 error: " + e);
        System.err.println("Check your input data");
        output = "An 404 error has occurred, more info:\n" + e + "\nCheck your input data";
        Log.d("LyricFinder", e.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Some error: " + e);
        output = "An uknown error has occurred\nCheck your internet connection";
        Log.d("LyricFinder", e.toString());
    }
    return output;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String lyrics) {
    lyricsOutput.setText(lyrics);
}
```

}
And logs are:

```
D/LyricFinder: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{www.azlyrics.com:80, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=85.17.159.246 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
```

In eclipse console project this code works perfectly (but without this asynctask :/ )
Idk what to do, because my question remain unanswered

Comment: Hey there, I copied your code and ran it on my machine, it ran perfectly without any errors. Perhaps it's your url that you are having issue with? can you try run your code with http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/linkinpark/intheend.html this url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection (Android, jsoup)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34073624/java-io-ioexception-unexpected-end-of-stream-on-connection-android-jsoup)

Comment: @JoelMin it's help... may be... java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL: azlyrics.com/lyrics/linkinpark/intheend.html

Comment: Sorry I mean `http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/linkinpark/intheend.html` this url

Comment: @JoelMin `new GetLyrics().execute("http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/linkinpark/intheend.html");`
Same result (ioexception)

Comment: @JoelMin and i tested on `virtual nexus 5 6.0` and `my lenovo a806 4.4.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so on another forum I found the solution:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get();
```